# Pod deletion strategy during rolling update

Tags: kubernetes

Does Kubernetes have any strategy of picking which older version pods to be deleted during rolling update? I didn't find any existing documents describing this.

Answer (score 2):

Pods are supposed to be ephemeral and disposable, and thus if you *do* care about their ordering, you'd want to use a [`StatefulSet` with `podManagementPolicy:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#statefulsetspec-v1-apps) which allows you to control the order they are created and then destroyed.